# Create named range with cells where value matches?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with two columns:

```
Employee    Company
970423-4829 Vete
970212-2398 AlfaLaval
970212-2398 DeLaval
970423-4829 Verktyg
970423-4829 Verktyg
960822-7587 Arla
970423-4829 test3
961225-7590 Test
970911-1287 Kamel
970911-1287 Kanel
```

I want to create a named range that contains all company lines for a certain employee.

If "employee" is 970212-2398, then I want the range to be

```
AlfaLaval
DeLaval
```

If "employee" is 970911-1287, then I want the range to be

```
Kamel
Kanel
```

Is this possible using Excel and/or VBA?

Comment: Are the employee IDs sorted?

Comment: How are you choosing which "certain employee" you wan to create the name for?  What will you be using these named ranges for?  Is the "table" really a "Table", or just a 2-column list? If it is a Table, what is its name? What have you tried so far to accomplish this task?

Comment: It's actually really an Excel table. The IDs are not sorted. We can pretend that the "certain emplyee" is located in A1. I will use the range/resulting list as a data validation drop down.

Comment: You write you want the "range to be" and then you list two names, on two separate lines.  Please clarify.

Comment: I suggest you search for Dependent Drop Down lists and use what you find to get started.

Comment: I would not recommend using a named range for unsorted data since you are limited on which functions will accept a range with multiple areas.

Comment: He should be able to generate the dependent dropdown list using a simple filter.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some dissenting comments that suggest you would be better off with another solution but this looked like an ideal sub for a `Scripting.Dictionary` object and I like to work with them so here you go.

```
Sub create_employee_named_ranges()
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, vEMP As Variant
    Dim dEMPs As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dEMPs.CompareMode = TextCompare

    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Not dEMPs.Exists(.Cells(r, 1).Value) Then
                dEMPs.Add Key:=.Cells(r, 1).Value, _
                  Item:=Chr(39) & .Name & Chr(39) & Chr(33) & .Cells(r, 2).Address
            Else
                dEMPs.Item(.Cells(r, 1).Value) = _
                  dEMPs.Item(.Cells(r, 1).Value) & Chr(44) & Chr(39) & .Name & Chr(39) & Chr(33) & .Cells(r, 2).Address
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For n = 1 To .Names.Count
            If Left(.Names(n).Name, 4) = "enr_" Then _
                .Names(n).Delete
        Next n
        For Each vEMP In dEMPs
            .Names.Add Name:="enr_" & Replace(vEMP, Chr(45), Chr(95)), _
              RefersTo:=Chr(61) & dEMPs.Item(vEMP)
        Next vEMP
    End With

    dEMPs.RemoveAll: Set dEMPs = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will have to go into the VBE's *Tools, References* and add `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to the list. Note that I could not use the actual employee identifier as dashes are illegal characters in the name of a named range (probably due to their use in subtraction) so I replaced them with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is generate a dropdown list, based on selecting a particular employee, I would suggest that you select the employee from the filter in that column of the table.  You can then run a VBA macro, either automatically upon a worksheet_change event, or manually with a button set up to run the macro, to generate the dropdown list.

Here is an example that will set up the "company drop down" in cell A1 based on what you select for an employee ID (or multiple ID's).

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub MakeCompanyList()
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim colCompanies As Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Dim RW As Long
    Dim S() As String

Set LO = Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

'Get company list from the visible rows
Set colCompanies = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
With LO.ListColumns("Company").DataBodyRange
    For I = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If .Rows(I).Hidden = False Then _
            colCompanies.Add .Rows(I).Value, CStr(.Rows(I).Value)
    Next I
End With
On Error GoTo 0

ReDim S(1 To colCompanies.Count)
For I = 1 To UBound(S)
    S(I) = colCompanies(I)
Next I

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(S, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = "Select a Company"
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "Selec a Company"
        .ErrorMessage = "Oops"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---